# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let

Tags: javascript, function

Estoy viendo un tutorial de funciones flecha y al reescribir la función anónima aparece este error en consola:

```js
let saludo = function(nombre) {
  return 'Saludos ' + nombre;
}

console.log(saludo('David'));
```

*Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let saludo
 debugger eval code:1
debugger eval code:1:1
 debugger eval code:1*

¿A qué se debe el error? He estado leyendo un poco sobre el asunto, pero parece estar bien.

Comment: `redeclaration of let saludo` significa que en alguna parte de tu código ya tienes una variable o una función con el mismo nombre: `saludo`.

Comment: Sí, es que el fin de semana estuve practicando y tuve una duda, pero la resolví y no tenía idea que quedaba la pregunta a guardada. Ahí lo corregí. Y con respecto al código, sólo escribí en consola lo que pegué en el comentario, no he reescrito la variable.

Comment: Que bueno que hayas podido resolver, de todos modos no hay función flecha en el ejemplo que pasaste, solo hay una forma de declarar funciones llamada  function expression.

Comment: Ah, sí. Es que el vídeo trata sobre funciones flecha, pero explica qué es una función anónima antes de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentaré responder en base al título y al error comentado, espero te sea de ayuda.

La siguiente función:

```
let saludo = function(nombre) {
  return 'Saludos ' + nombre;
}

console.log(saludo('David'));
```

Es una función del tipo function expression, puedes ver más información en el siguiente link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

---

Podría también haber sido declarada de la siguiente manera:

```
function saludo(nombre) {
  return 'Saludos ' + nombre;
}

console.log(saludo('David'));
```

A esto se le conoce como function declaration, puedes encontrar información en el siguiente link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

---

Si lo que deseas es escribirlo como una arrow function, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let saludo = (nombre) => {
  return 'Saludos ' + nombre;
}

console.log(saludo('David'));
```

Al ser una arrow function puedes hacer varias cosas como quitar las llaves, quitar los paréntesis si es un único parámetro el que recibe y quitar el return ya que las arrow function lo traen implícito.

Quedando el código anterior de la siguiente manera:

```
let saludo = nombre => 'Saludos ' + nombre;

console.log(saludo('David'));
```

A continuación dejo link a documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

---

Referente al error "Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let saludo debugger eval code:1 debugger eval code:1:1 debugger eval code:1"

Esto indica que existe una variable saludo del tipo let y que estás en alguna parte redeclarando saludo.